# Is davmail gone?

Tags: 12.04, repository, davmail

I've searched a lot but neither in the documentation nor in google i can find something about the missing davmail. I don't have updated my Ubuntu to a newer release and just realized my exchange calendar is not available, my davmail icon is gone, davmail is not installed, davmail is not available in the software center and davmail is also not available on ppa.

Is davmail just a mirage? I'm confused there is no wiki entry on http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de..

Comment: Does [this](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/) help?

Comment: thanks. i know the davmail project page and i know that i don't downloaded a package to install davmail. my question is not "how to install davmail on 12.04"... i'm just wondering why it is no longer available in the repos...